# how to make corner based gradient drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to make gradient background that placed only bottom right.
(Sorry for images because I don't have enough rep for inline)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebgWn.jpg

First, I made radial gradient but not perfect

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:centerX="0.9"
        android:centerY="1"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:gradientRadius="40%p"
        android:startColor="#BF000000"
        android:type="radial" />
</shape>
```

It looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOqFf.jpg

Then, I made linear gradient but still not perfect.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:endColor="#CD000000"
        android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0y9C.jpg

Because **gradientRadius** parameter doesn't work with linear gradient. Are there any starting/ending point parameter for this gradient? Thanks for help!

Comment: Why not have time and tick views wrapped inside a Layout and add linear gradient background only to this layout ..

Answer (score 0):

Best i have tried with

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
        android:centerX="0.8"
        android:centerY="1"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:gradientRadius="80%p"
        android:startColor="#BF000000"
        android:type="radial" />
```

And then Wrap your `TextView` and Tick Icon together inside a layout and set the above background to it..

If you want the exact same effect as you provided in image then you better use a Image or vector file for it .. But the approach will be same setting the background to only Wrapped layout not the Root.